Craft 5.4 // Replace Neo with Matrix // any experiences?
I'm still on Craft 4.x and a Neo heavy user.
First off, Neo is a brilliant plugin – many thanks to Spicy Web!
But I still think about replacing Neo with the new features of Craft 5.x (such as the Matrix field).
This would be a lot of work, so I just wanted to ask if there are any experiences or maybe best practices by now. I’m aware of the available resources online, but blog posts and manuals sometimes don’t address the “devil in the details.”

Are there any Neo features that can’t be replicated with Matrix fields?
What about performance aspects?
How well do Matrix fields handle multi-language, multi-user, or multi-site setups?
[...] ?

Thanks a lot for some input / ideas / experiences!
